# Store user-defined object in numpy array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, object, numpy-ndarray

How can I store an object of user-defined class in numpy array ?

I have a class like this:

```
class Node():
   
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.g = 0

import numpy as np

def main():
        node1 = Node()
        node2 = Node()

        my_array = np.empty( shape=(2, 3), dtype = 'Node' )
        my_array[0][1] = node1
        my_array[1][1] = node2

        print(my_array)
```

The above code throws the error: `TypeError: data type "Node" not understood`.

Comment: use dtype='O' for any Python object as described in the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.object_). I recommend reading the docs in general. 99.8% of the time, it solves my problems instantly.

Comment: @yannziselman  As a teacher, I encourage new users to try to find information in the documentation BUT I recognize the struggle of new users. I know that despite decades of tech work, I often come across docs that are difficult for me to understand. New vocabulary I don't yet understand OR words used in ways I don't expect. Often when searching for how to do something I don't have the vocabulary to search 'cause I don't know what the concept is called in the new technology. Docs are written by experts/skilled programmers, who may not be experts in writing tech content geared toward learners.

Comment: @E.Ducateme ok.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

```
class Node():
   
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.g = 0

import numpy as np

def main():
        node1 = Node()
        node2 = Node()

        my_array = np.empty( shape=(2, 3), dtype = object)
        my_array[0][1] = node1
        my_array[1][1] = node2

        print(my_array)
```

Solution 2:

```
class Node1():
   
    def __init__(self,data):
        
        self.g = 0
        self.data= 1

import numpy as np

def main():
        node1 = Node1(1)
        node2 = Node1(2)

        my_array = np.empty( shape=(2, 3), dtype = np.dtype(Node1))
        my_array[0][1] = node1
        my_array[1][1] = node2

        print(my_array)
```

Please go through document: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Comment: thank you. I used both of them during trials and settled with 1st one as it is independent of any existing object.

Comment: Check the resulting dtypes.  The second doesn't do anything different.

Comment: That's true @hpaulj. I just wanted to show an example if you want to create a custom datatype

Comment: @hpaulj I had checked the resulting dtype by printing it. But I could not assign the resulting dtype using ```dtype = 'resulting_dtype' ```. So, the only option left was to use ``` dtype = object``` or ``` dtype = type(node1)```. I feel I am missing something ? Please let me know how to use the resulting dtype shown by print.

Comment: What BhavinT is trying to point out is that `np.dtype(YourClass)` produces a `Object` dtype.  In your example `np.empty( shape=(2, 3), dtype = Node')` would also produce the Object dtype.  It's the string value that is not "recognized".  The string `'Node'` is not your class.  `dtype='int32'` works because the string has been "registered" with `np.dtype`.  It recognizes it.

Comment: @hpaulj So, you mean to say that I should have used ```np.dtype(YourClass)``` instead of ```dtype = Node ``` ??

Comment: No, don't take me so literally.  I just just use `YourClass` because because I didn't off hand remember your class's name.  You may need to do some more basic Python reading to get a better sense of the differences between strings, variables and objects.  `numpy` runs in python.

Comment: Oh, I actually didn't took literally. :) I mean ``` np.dtype('Node') ```

Comment: @hpaulj I know the difference between strings, variables and objects. I was only asking help for syntax. It should not be expected to remember all the syntaxes of all the languages.

Comment: @aks Go through this link : https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Comment: @aks Is the answer incorrect. Let me know so I can look more closely

Comment: Tick it so in future other people can refer it@aks

Comment: `np.dtype('Node')` won't work either.

Comment: Something else to consider.  Storing user-defined objects in a  numpy array does not provide much (any?) added functionality.  A list and list comprehensions are usually easier to use.

Comment: @hpaulj Ok, I should register the string before using it as a dtype. It would have been really appreciated had you given what exactly would work if ```np.dtype('Node')``` won't.

Comment: @hpaulj I mean could you provide exact instruction to replace 
```my_array = np.empty( shape=(2, 3), dtype = np.dtype('Node'))```

Comment: Forget about using the string `'Node'`.  There's no connection between that string and your `Node` class.  If you aren't using a builtin dtype like `int32`, the only way to store your `Node` instances in an array is as `object` dtype.  And for all practical purposes that's the same as list, `[node1, node2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your class with a minor enhancement:

```
In [198]: class Node():
     ...:     def __init__(self,i):
     ...:         self.g = i
     ...:     def __repr__(self):
     ...:         return "<Node %s %s>"%(self.g, id(self))
     ...: 
     ...: node1 = Node(1)
     ...: node2 = Node(2)
     ...:
```

The instances:

```
In [199]: node1
Out[199]: <Node 1 140575230534224>
In [200]: node2
Out[200]: <Node 2 140575230535904>
```

a list containing the instances:

```
In [201]: alist = [node1, node2]
In [202]: alist
Out[202]: [<Node 1 140575230534224>, <Node 2 140575230535904>]
```

An object dtype array:

```
In [203]: arr = np.empty(3, dtype=object)
In [204]: arr
Out[204]: array([None, None, None], dtype=object)
```

Like a list it can "hold" an instance, a number, or a list of nodes:

```
In [205]: arr[0]=node1
In [206]: arr[1]=123
In [207]: arr[2]=[node2, node1]
In [208]: arr
Out[208]: 
array([<Node 1 140575230534224>, 123,
       list([<Node 2 140575230535904>, <Node 1 140575230534224>])],
      dtype=object)
```

Use list comprehension to fetch the attribute:

```
In [209]: [a.g for a in alist]
Out[209]: [1, 2]
```

or conditional fetch - from the list or array:

```
In [211]: [a.g for a in alist if isinstance(a,Node)]
Out[211]: [1, 2]
In [212]: [a.g for a in arr if isinstance(a,Node)]
Out[212]: [1]
```

the array itself can't fetch instance attributes:

```
In [213]: arr.g
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-213-b925e810105d>", line 1, in <module>
    arr.g
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'g'
```